# How do I find the sum of each number multiplied by its position in the array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can sum each value in the array but I can't figure out how to get the sum of each number multiplied by its position in the array.

Comment: Sounds like *your* homework.

Comment: I figured out how to sum the elements in the array but not how to multiply them: 

var myArray = [1,2,3,4];

var mySum=0;

for(var i in myArray)

(mySum += myArray[i])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable that stores product of the index and array element. Then add that to array element and store it to sum.

```
var myProd=1; 
var mySum=0;
for(var i = 0 ; i<myArray.length() ; i++) 
{
    myProd = (i+1)*myArray[i];
    mySum+=(myArray[i]+myProd);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot!

Comment: @aliyahmaliyah mark as answer, it would be great :D

Comment: this helped but it turns out I mucked up the Q and I was supposed to frame it in terms of a function. I swear I'm not trying to get you to do my hw for me :) I just am so stuck and can't seem to get passed this. Are you able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: @aliyahmaliyah yeasure

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `reduce` method for arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```js
var myArray = [1,2,3,4];

var result = myArray.reduce(function(prev, curr, index) {
  return prev + (curr * index);
}, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Which is effectively the same as `(1*0 + 2*1 + 3*2 + 4*3)`

Answer (score 0):

Define a function to sum up the values in an array:

```
function sum(array) { return array.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }); }
```

Now create an array of each value multiplied by its position, then apply `sum` to it:

```
sum(myArray.map(function(elt, idx) { return elt * idx; }))
```

In ES6, you can write this more compactly:

```
function sum(array) { return array.reduce((a, b) => a + b); }

sum(myArray.map((elt, idx) => elt * idx));
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using map with reduce, when reduce has access to the array index and all array values?

Comment: I guess it's personal preference. Nothing wrong with your approach.